# Super slow compile time

Tags: go

I was using Go normally  in my computer and it was compiling really fast (< 1s), but unfortunately after the visual studio code Go plugin asked me to install a bunch of things my Go become super slow, a simple code like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

Is taking more than 10 seconds to execute:

```
[Running] go run "c:\dev\workspace\go\test\src\main.go"
Hello

[Done] exited with code=0 in 45.596 seconds

[Running] go run "c:\dev\workspace\go\test\src\main.go"
Hello

[Done] exited with code=0 in 16.242 seconds

[Running] go run "c:\dev\workspace\go\test\src\main.go"
Hello

[Done] exited with code=0 in 14.759 seconds

[Running] go run "c:\dev\workspace\go\test\src\main.go"
Hello

[Done] exited with code=0 in 15.492 seconds

[Running] go run "c:\dev\workspace\go\test\src\main.go"
Hello

[Done] exited with code=0 in 16.047 seconds
```

What I already have tried:

- Uninstalled everything and installed again;
- Changed Go version to 1.4 (it improved the compile time, but
  nothing really big, like in this    version it compiled in ~7
  seconds, what still making it slow)
- Tried other IDE (Idea)

Now I'm using the latest Go version:

```
$ go version
go version go1.15.2 windows/amd64
```

My "go env":

```
$ go env
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\ticunha\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\ticunha\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\dev\workspace\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\dev\workspace\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=c:\go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=c:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\ticunha\AppData\Local\Temp\1\go-build323480842=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Has anyone been through this and could give me some light on this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Such slow compilation may indicate you have a different Go SDK installed than your current platform or the platform indicated by the `GOOS` and `GOARCH` environment variables, which would require having to recompile the standard lib to the target platform every time. Check that if you have 64-bit architecture, you should have the windows-amd64 SDK (and not the windows-386 for example).

Comment: Note that `go run` times are compilation *and execution*, not just compilation.

Comment: "Changed Go version to 1.4 " -- I hope that's not actually what you did. Go 1.4 is ancient... not to mention much _slower_.

Comment: The `[Running] ... [Done]` sequence you posted comes from the `Output` tab of vscode, correct ? do you see the same slowness when executing `go run .../main.go` from an external console ? and from the embedded terminal in vscode ?

Answer (score 1):

Check first if the issue persists in command line (CLI)

If it does, then make sure this is not a `PATH` issue, by setting in that same CMD session a simplified PATH:

```sh
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
set PATH=%USERPROFILE%\go\bin;%PATH%
set PATH=c:\go\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: I did this, but the same problem remains. slowness persists in all tools and even in the CMD.

Comment: @tiagomac What version of Widows are you working with?