# How can i ssh with VScode 1.53.2 to an Ubuntu 14.04 VM server

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, windows-7, ubuntu-14.04

Using VS code to ssh into an Ubuntu 14.04 server. At first i couldn't even connect, but after installing git for windows after putting password i get: Could not establish connection to "Host name".
I can ssh into this server with putty or powershell.

This is the output on VS code:

```
[13:55:01.574] Got password response
[13:55:01.575] "install" wrote data to terminal: "********************"
[13:55:01.605] > 
> 
[13:55:04.040] "install" terminal command done
[13:55:04.040] Install terminal quit with output: 
[13:55:04.040] Received install output: 
[13:55:04.041] Stopped parsing output early. Remaining text: 
[13:55:04.041] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[13:55:04.048] Resolver error: Error: 
    at Function.Create (c:\Users\Turro\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.64.0\out\extension.js:1:64126)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\Turro\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.64.0\out\extension.js:1:62865)
    at k (c:\Users\Turro\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.64.0\out\extension.js:1:313462)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async c:\Users\Turro\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.64.0\out\extension.js:1:311339
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\Turro\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.64.0\out\extension.js:1:406337)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\Turro\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.64.0\out\extension.js:1:315001)
    at async c:\Users\Turro\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.64.0\out\extension.js:127:110431
[13:55:04.054] ------
```

Thanks in advance, ill be glad to pass any more information required to solve this problem!

Answer (score 1):

> I can ssh into this server with putty or powershell.

That could mean you are using an SSH key with [putty ppk format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74628/7490) instead of OpenSSH.

Try and launch VSCode from a session where:

- the `%PATH%` does not reference Putty (but does include Git, and its `usr/bin` folder)
- the `GIT_SSH` environment variable is set to `ssh` (although it should not be needed, if the PATH is correctly set)

Comment: I might not quite understand what you mean, but i checked the %PATH% and there's no reference to Putty. I checked and i can ssh from the git bash in windows, yet i still cant with VS code. Can this be because the extensions might not support connecting to an Ubuntu 14.04? if this is the case, is there any other extension to do so?

Comment: @DiegoSusviela First, make sure your PATH reference the folders I mention in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64151986/6309 (you don't need the go folder though)

Comment: Just added all those folders to my PATH, now i just keep getting asked the password until i get an error message: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

Comment: Password means the public keys was not properly (or at all) registered on the server side.

Comment: i do not understand why i get this error,i can use that password to log via putty or git bash

Comment: @DiegoSusviela password or passphrase? Try with an openssh key without passphrase: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -P "" -f ~/.ssh/newKey`

Comment: mm i tried something similar before, if i run that on the server im trying to connect, i get a key fingerprint and a randomart image (before i tried connecting with the public key generated, probably in doing something wrong in this regard), what should i do from there? sorry for my lack of knowledge

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228714/discussion-between-vonc-and-diego-susviela).

Answer (score 0):

From the doc of vscode: `https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh` .
system requirements:

```
Local: A supported OpenSSH compatible SSH client must also be installed.
Remote SSH host: A running SSH server on:
x86_64 Debian 8+, Ubuntu 16.04+, CentOS / RHEL 7+.
ARMv7l (AArch32) Raspberry Pi OS (previously called Raspbian) Stretch/9+ (32-bit).
ARMv8l (AArch64) Ubuntu 18.04+ (64-bit).
Windows 10 / Server 2016/2019 (1803+) using the official OpenSSH Server.
macOS 10.14+ (Mojave) SSH hosts with Remote Login enabled.
1 GB RAM is required for remote hosts, but at least 2 GB RAM and a 2-core CPU is recommended.
Other glibc based Linux distributions for x86_64, ARMv7l (AArch32), and ARMv8l (AArch64) should work if they have the needed prerequisites. See the Remote Development with Linux article for information prerequisites and tips for getting community supported distributions up and running.
While ARMv7l (AArch32) and ARMv8l (AArch64) support is available, some extensions installed on these devices may not work due to the use of x86 native code in the extension
```

Comment: How do you know system requirements are the problem in OP's case?